# Associate my own data with google places api data

Tags: google-places-api

I have my own database for places and locations that I extracted from geonames export or added manually. My question is : can I associate my locations with Google Places (using place_id) so that I can show more data in my pages that I can get from Google Places without breaking Google guidelines and restrictions. I know of course that I can't store data extracted from google places api in my database.